React MUI Cards not able to have same height
I have a dashboard with 3 cards which has 3 seperate components called in them. The height of the cards expand according to the content each has. I want to have all 3 cards have the same heights as the one with the heighest height. So if one of the card lengthens according to its content, the other 2 should increase in height as well. I am using MUI for React.So basically , the dashboard has a first row with 3 components as below. Inside each component I have used Card to style.
<Container maxWidth="lg">
      <Grid container spacing={2}> 
        <Grid item xs={6}>
           <Component1/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Component2/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Component3/>
       </Grid>
     </Grid>
 </Container>


can you create a sandbox replicating the issue

put inline css on your cards style={{height: '100%'}},
your problem would be solved
<Card style={{ height: '100%'}}>
see screenshot


let me know if issue not solved

It has solved but I don't want to use as inline. Is there any styles in MUI itself that can be added to the tag?

brother in mui we can add inline css like sx
replace sx with style
or you can add your custom className
